# How to trick a particular command into thinking it is a different date?

Tags: date, executable

How can I execute a command making it believe that is on a different date than system one?

For instance, if I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
date +"%B %d, %Y"
```

It prints the actual date: `march 13, 2014`

But I would like it to print a different date, on the future or past, without changing the system date.

If I wasn't clear enough, I want a command line tool like [this Windows GUI tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html).

---

I do not want to use a different script (it was just an example).
I do not want to set a *cronjob*.
I do not want to change my general system date.
Only change the date that apply to the command to run.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using the [libfaketime](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/) software could be a solution

```
sudo apt-get install faketime
faketime '2006-09-20' wine Example.exe
```

Comment: it did the trick on wine? i tested just on native binaries; cheers

Comment: I just tested it with Wine and I got LD_PRELOAD errors on libfaketime.so, so I found a windows tool called RunAsDate which works with Wine 1.6.2 and does the trick: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html